Some Bug with "Illuminator" Badge?
(0) While tracking "Illuminator" Badge, I generally see that when I answer some question, edit the question, get upvoted within the time limit then the current count increases, naturally.
(1) Yet, on multiple occasions, I have seen that when I answer some question, edit the question, get upvoted within the time limit then the current count increases, then with no other actions, the count drops, never to increase for the Current Post.
(2) Meanwhile, on rare occasions, I have seen that when I answer some question, edit the question, get upvoted within the time limit then the current count increases, then there is some downvote hence the count reduces (naturally) then there are more upvotes, then too the count never increases for the Current Post.
These two seem to be bugs.
My Questions:
(A) Does the Community know about this? Can somebody confirm or clarify the issue?
(B) Does the Community know how to generate the list of questions which are counted? [ I am thinking about SQL/DB Query Output ]
It might highlight the Bug.
At the least, that list will let me know what I am thinking wrongly.
This is what MSE says about "Illuminator" Badge:

How do you earn this badge?
Edit and answer 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)


Closed questions do not count for Explainer/Refiner/Illuminator. Is it possible that the count drops if the question was closed?

Tag-only edits don't count either.

I ensure that the count increases , hence it was not tag-only edits , @PeterPhipps , though the Badge Description is incomplete , not mentioning what you say.

Oh , that may be the Case , where the timing of closing some question matches the time just after the count increases , @MartinSleziak , Ideally the Badge Description should mention the terms more completely. Giving the SQL Query in general terms might make things totally clear.
